# What is tomcat or iis localhost port address in windwos phone 7/8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, tomcat, iis, windows-phone-8

I want to access the `localhost`in emulator of windows phone 7/8.

But at here i am using `10.0.0.205` before of the local host port number (l
    localhost:8080/index.html
 or `http://localhost:59131/Default.aspx`) when i want to access that its not displaying..

i tried with my LAN Ip and Default gateway ip and ipv4 address.. But its not working in emulator even though its running on emulator..

I am an android developer in android(java) i use this at localhost `10.0.2.2`

is there any way to display with the localhost not with the ip in emulator..
In android i done it...

Comment: i believe this question is specific to networking, try tag up with a proper one.

Comment: its not under networking Kelmen.. hey madhui think i should work with 10.0.0.205 or else you need to use ip address..

Comment: Hi  user3124880 i used may urls as i mentioned i used default ip and ipv4 but its not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually every developer mistakes like me..
when they are doing their same **android or ios** apps which are based on local host.. in **Windows Phone 7/8**

In android if your local host is..`http://localhost:59131/Default.aspx` we need to use `10.0.0.205`
Instead of `local host` so that the url will be.. `http://10.0.0.205:59131/Default.aspx`

But for Windows phone emulator we can Use `http://localhost:59131/Default.aspx`
directly with out any port number..

Since its supports virtuality i mean My System OS is Windows OS and Emulator is Windows So it doesn't make any change.. in LocalHost..

Where as for android or ios we need to use some other instead of `local host`.

and finally its worked for me.. and here we dont need to use our IP weather you are online or offline nothing matters..

its worked Fine..

Answer (score 1):

In order to access to your computer localhost IIS/Tomcat from Windows Phone emulator 7/8 you need to use your machine IP address. So if your computer IP is 192.168.1.123 in your app you need to try to access:
`http:// 192.168.1.123:59131/default.aspx`.

You need to be sure your IIS/Tomcat isn't blocked by your computer firewall.

Comment: hi Josue Yeray sir actually they are running as localhost in browser but i want to run it with ip its not working but its working with android when i use local host as 10.0.2.2 before port number i mean 10.0.2.2:8080/Default.aspx i have the same problem.. like madhu

Comment: Hey user3124880 let me ask first.. hai Josue Yeray sir.. that the problem i am having..

Comment: Hi! Are you sure you can access to your IIS/Tomcat from another computer in the same network (not firewall blocking your port) The wp emulators are virtual machines, and for this kind of things, they are like another machine in the network, they don't have direct access to your localhost. you need to access like you do with another machine.

Comment: no sir but i can able to access on emulator sir.. it works on android But its not working on windows phone.. i what to know what is local host address of windows phone,. some one said that its 10.0.0.205 but its not working.. is there any other way.. if there or how can i run my local host on another pc.. please help sir..

Comment: Madhu, you can't access to localhost of the Windows Phone emulator, as you can't have IIS on the emulator. From the emulator, you need to connect to the computer where your IIS is Running, and for that, the emulator is like another computer in the network.